# Why can't momentum be used to compare something moving linearly and something falling

Tags: energy, gravity, momentum, energy-conservation, potential-energy

We're having a discussion in the office about the difference between using momentum and kinetic energy. Here is the example scenario.

Discussing an equivalent height for something to fall compared to something moving in a straight line.

Let say for instance:

Mass 1 - 1kg - 50m/s

Mass 2 - 10kg - Falling at 1g.

---

Using Energies.

Mass 1 Kinetic Energy = 1250 J

Mass 2 would need to fall from 1250/[10*9.81] = 12.74m

I'm quite happy with this.

---

Using Momentum.

Mass 1 momentum = 50 kgm/s

Equating momentum (which I don't think you can do. I think this is the issue) for mass 2 means that we'd want the height it has fallen when it has the same momentum as the mass 1. So: 50/10=5m/s, using equations of motion the distance travelled would be s = 5^2 / [2*9.81] = 1.27m.

---

I don't even think that you can do it by equating momentum because the falling object also has the force of gravity acting on it. Curiously, when you do this you end up with two answers that are out by a factor of the mass which as got us interested. It feels like there is a link somewhere that we can't figure out!

What is the physics behind this? Thanks

Comment: 'Falling at 1g" has no meaning or is is incomplete information, therefore Mass 2 cannot be calculated.

Comment: Why are you comparing different masses?

Comment: -1. Unclear. As Carl Lei points out, you have not specified what you want to be "equivalent" about the two situations.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define "equivalent", which usually is the effects made by its interacting with others.

Imagine a bullet shot into a chunk of wood and embedded in there.  What drop height would be needed (excluding air drag) for another bullet of the same shape but different mass to

- get to the same depth into the wood chunk?
- take the wood chunk to the same speed?

Comment: Well this is part of the problem we were discussing. I guess you could say it would be to get to the same depth into the wood chunk or do damage. My POV was that you couldn't just say "when the momentum of M2 in the air is the same as M1" because that would then go on be different as the effect would be an impact with an object that has an impulse.